# How i configure or download cmake in Android Studio 2.2 in SDK Tools

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I checked many questions but I can't find any working answer and in screenshot not showing any option for download  cmake from SDK Tools

[image: cmake download option is not shown in sdk tools]

Comment: go with code sample

Comment: Could You please describe properly the environment, things You've tried and stuff You need to be done?

Comment: Yes Tired several  way to set cmake,  but i dont know how it is working, I simply download Android studio  Endless Tunnel sample from Sample  repo.